# My jQuery UI Dialog doesn't open if not preceded by an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dialog

At the start of my HTML page, the definition of my dialog :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    height:180,
    width:300,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Yes": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      },
      "No": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Test dialog">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>You can press Yes or No</p>
</div>
```

And after at the end of my HTML page, the place in which I want to open my dialog (inputText is an input got by Id)  :

```
inputText.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  if (event.which == 13 || event.which == 10)
  {
    alert("test");
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  }
});
```

My problem is if I don't put the `alert("test");`, my dialog won't open when I type enter in my input.

What can I do to remove the alert and to keep the proper operation ?

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent the default behavior of the alert by doing this:

```
inputText.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.which == 13 || event.which == 10)
  {
    alert("test");
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  }
});
```

the key 13 and 10 are for the enter key, if you don't prevent the default behavior, then when your dialog show, the first button will be focused and the enter key will trigger the click on this button.

So, prevent the click by doing a `event.preventDefault();`